# Power App reading in value as blank or null and outputting a 0 in the SP List

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

There is a numeric column in my Power App Form called Order Value. The user enter a value or not. If I leave it blank and press submit . It somehow ends up as 0 and not blank or null in the SharePoint List the Power App writes to . Is there a way to work round this ?

The order value field is numeric in the form . In the SharePoint List the end output column, Order Value in number as well.

I did see this on Microsoft site ....

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Ideas/Allow-us-to-update-a-numeric-field-to-null-blank-value/idi-p/11700

Comment: Did you set the default value of number column to 0 in column settings in SharePoint?

Comment: There is this in validation settings - =IF(AND([Order Rental Value]+[Order Labour Value]+[Order Transport Value]<>[Order Value],[Detailed Order Values]="Yes"),FALSE,TRUE) 

Detailed Order Value is No for entries I am trying to insert